# Typescript 2 with Angular 2

Tags: angular

I have an app in Angular 2 and Typescript & typings, it works well but I have to upgrade to TypeScript 2 and I don't understand how can I do this thing.

I'm using leaflet, pako and md5 and when I install @types/pako for example, I can't start my app cause of a lot of error like this :

> D:/Mini/final2/node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/async.d.ts:35:44
>   Cannot find name 'Promise'.

Same for pako, leaflet, md5 and co

Here I have my package.json:

```js
{
  "name": "suivi-gps-mini-v2",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Starting pack for angular2, typescript, typings and webpack, all config for prod mod.",
  "main": "main.ts",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server -d --inline --progress --port 8080 --host 0.0.0.0",
    "build": "rimraf dist && webpack --config config/webpack.prod.js --progress --profile --bail && node ./tools/appcache.js && node clean.js",
    "lite": "lite-server",
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "tsc:w": "tsc -w"
  },
  "author": "DMIC",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/forms": "0.2.0",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "core-js": "^2.4.0",
    "leaflet": "1.0.1",
    "material-design-icons": "^3.0.0",
    "md5": "^2.1.0",
    "pako": "^1.0.3",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.6"
    "zone.js": "^0.6.12"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/core-js": "^0.9.34",
    "@types/leaflet": "^1.0.36",
    "@types/md5": "^2.1.31",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.46",
    "@types/pako": "^0.2.31",
    "angular2-template-loader": "^0.4.0",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "^1.1.1",
    "concurrently": "^2.0.0",
    "css-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^1.0.1",
    "file-loader": "^0.8.5",
    "find-remove": "^0.2.12",
    "html-loader": "^0.4.3",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.15.0",
    "ncp": "^2.0.0",
    "null-loader": "^0.1.1",
    "phantomjs-prebuilt": "^2.1.7",
    "raw-loader": "^0.5.1",
    "rimraf": "^2.5.2",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.1",
    "typescript": "^2.0.3",
    "webpack": "^1.13.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.14.1",
    "webpack-merge": "^0.14.0"
  }
}
```

and my tsconfig:

```js
{
 "compilerOptions": {
  "target": "es5",
  "module": "commonjs",
  "moduleResolution": "node",
  "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
  "experimentalDecorators": true,
  "removeComments": false,
  "noImplicitAny": false,
  "declaration": true
 },

 "exclude": [
  "node_modules"
 ]

}
```

EDIT: I update my package.json (still doesn't work).

Comment: So you have already installed TypeScript 2.0 on your system? Which editor do you use?

Comment: Yep with : npm install -g typescript@2.0, i'm using visual studio code

Comment: Visual Studio Code should automatically work with the version you have installed with npm, and your project should not have to change.

Comment: My problelm isn't my IDE, in fact i'm using typescript 1 and my project works well but some week ago, typescript 2.0 comes i i'd like to upgrade my typescript 1.0 to typescript 2.0 by install typescript@2.0 and delete typings because typescript can now handle declaration file with this syntax npm install --save @types/LIBNAME but when i'am installing all my lib like this i have this error : D:/Mini/final2/node_modules/@angular/core/src/facade/async.d.ts:35:44 Cannot find name 'Promise' and same for all my other libs

Comment: If that is the problem, then why is the title of your question "Typescript 2 with angular 2"?

Comment: Because i'm talking about typescript 2 with angular, are you there for helping me or just taunting me? :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to add --lib es6 option to compiler, or to tsconfig file like this:

```
"compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "lib": ["es6", "es2015"]
}
```

Comment: Same problem, Cannot find name 'Promise' and same for all my lib ( leaflet, pako, md5), 
I'm trying to delete typings to my projet for use the declaration file given by typescript2